# Why decimal does not pre-fill while integer does?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I come to you because I have a little problem in HTML, I create a field to fill with a number, this same field I prefilled when loading the page. I'm supposed to fill it with a number that can be either an integer or a decimal.
The problem is that when I pre-fill it with a decimal, it does not display the value! This problem does not appear when I pre-fill it with an integer (when I say pre-fill it's via code obviously, not by hand).

Unfortunately, I did not find how to solve this problem after several hours of research.

```html
<dt class="col-sm-3 detailsElements">
                    <img src="~/images/time.png" /> Temps prévu
                </dt>
                <dd class="col-sm-9 detailsElements">
                    <input asp-for="ExceptedTime" class="form-control" type="number" step=".01" required/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="ExceptedTime" class="text-danger"></span>
                </dd>
```

Here's what it gives me:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeh7Y.png
Here is the code of the page (we see that the value is 2.4 but yet nothing is displayed):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFY1E.png

I do not put screens with an integer since it works.

So someone has an idea? Thank you in advance !

Comment: The value in the screen shot is 2,4 rather than 2.4.

Comment: I am in France and we use the comma to make decimals

Comment: Have you tried setting the body language `lang` property to French?

Comment: No, how to do that ?

Comment: Why don't you paste the code in your post instead of posting an image of the code?

Comment: I put the corresponding code, why are you saying that?

Comment: @Vich 1) The code you posted is incomplete: it does not have the attribute that causes the problem! 2) Have you actually tried the suggestions? If so, and it still doesn't work, post what you currently have. Meanwhile, I made [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/nt0rcwjm/4/) and it works as desired, so if you don't show your code, we can't tell what is wrong with it.

Comment: I have finally found a solution, I was right, the problem was the code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

For input with type equal to number you need to use correct format, it's the same as js, with dots. Just try changing it.

Comment: So I have to use dot rather than comma ? Because when we force user to enter a number, he can only enter integer or decimal with comma and not decimal with dot !! So how to make that ?

Comment: Just try it, it will work. That's what `number` inputs are for! The value will be "2.4" and it will be displayed as `2,4` on the screen.

Comment: The standard is use dots, it's based on american system. There is nothing to do, just adapt to it

Comment: @IvanGonzalez Why the input don't want the dot but accept the comma ? https://i.imgur.com/Box9FCE.png

Answer (score 0):

That was the solution of my problem :
I added a value with C# and replace coma with dot.

```html
<dd class="col-sm-9 detailsElements">
                    <input asp-for="ExceptedTime" value="@Model.ExceptedTime.ToString().Replace(",",".")" class="form-control" type="number" step=".01" required/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="ExceptedTime" class="text-danger"></span>
                </dd>
```

Comment: OK. Be sure to also replace the dot back with a comma when retrieving the value.